# Is it possible to use Excel Solver outside of the Excel Application?

Tags: excel, vba, solver

Excel solver is amazing and wondering if its possible to incorporate the Solver functionality into a web based app instead of keeping everything in Excel. My guess is no because solver solutions are cell based.

On second thought, there is probably a similar solver available with python.

Comment: Why not check out the company that provides the Solver?

Comment: And also there are other programs that can do the equivalent mathematics... Wolfram Alpha, Matlab just to conjure two names...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but extremely far fetched. You would have to set up Excel on the web server, which makes crazy things to the licensing. Once there, you will have to run Excel in a separate process, but control it from your web app. Using interop in .net might be the least stupid way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

So just a couple of links to point you in the right direction:

1. https://www.solver.com/frontline-systems-releases-next-generation-solver-add-in-optimization-excel-online-and-excel-2016

The last few paragraphs point out that you can use the solver with RASOn, JSON C++, R, Python etc in your own apps so that is an option for you.

2. https://www.solver.com/

Is the homepage of the company that provides the Solver, and access to the more powerful version that  exceeds the built-in version in Excel - good though that is. I have not needed the larger version - just turned a model or two around to reduce the computing needs.